# Extracting the Projected Data in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

When we add a trendline to a chart, Excel provides an option to display the trendline equation in the chart. 
We can then use these formulas to calculate predicted y values for give values of x
The formulea are nicely listed by [SpreadSheetPage.Com](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/chart_trendline_formulas/)

I wanted to implement the same in the excel sheet for a dataset like given below:

```
Year Value
1990  400
1991  494
1992  449
1993  554
1994  600
1995  499
1996
1997
1998
1999
2000
```

As you can see, I wanted to project the values for the years 1996 to 2000 using 2nd Order Polynomial.

Using the equations provided by [SpreadSheetPage.Com](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/chart_trendline_formulas/)

2nd Order Polynomial Trendline

```
Equation: y = (c2 * x^2) + (c1 * x ^1) + b
c2: =INDEX(LINEST(y,x^{1,2}),1)
C1: =INDEX(LINEST(y,x^{1,2}),1,2)
b = =INDEX(LINEST(y,x^{1,2}),1,3)
```

I calculated C2 and the stored the value in a cell whith cell address say C2.
Similarly, I calculated C1 and stored the value in a cell with cell address say C1. I also calculated b and stored the value in a cell with cell address say C3.

Then, in the cell besides the year 1996 (whoes value I want to project), I entered the formulea  = (c2 * x^2) + (c1 * x ^1) + C3 and Ctr+Shift+Entered for the array formulea while selected the value cells from 1996-2000.

The results were not as expected. I am sure I am not using these equations in their proper way. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Please not I have made named arrays x and y for known x's and known y's respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the limitation that you don't provide your actual or expected results:
Assume your known table is A1:B7, and your ranges are named as you mentioned:

```
B8:  = (C$2 * A8^2) + (C$1 * A8 ^1) + C$3
```

and fill down to B12

[image]

Using a different function, you could use:

```
B8: =TREND(y,x^{1,2},A8:A12^{1,2})
```

Then select B8:B12 and enter as an array with `ctrl+shift+enter`.  Note that this function may be inaccurate in versions of Excel prior to 2007.

**EDIT**
Note that the original formula can be entered as an array if we replace `A8` with `A8:A12`; and the `TREND` function can be entered normally, and filled down, if `new_x` is entered as a single cell, instead of a range.

Comment: Thank you very much Ron Rosenfeld!

Instead of cell addresses (in your case A8), I was putting range name x and that was the problem.

Comment: @Rouf Also, with your formula, and also with my `TREND` function, there is no need to enter as an array if you just refer to a single cell.